# Rewriting quadratic expression

Tags: quadratics, factoring, quadratic-forms, rewriting-systems

I am currently learning how to factorise quadratic expressions of the form $ax^2 + bx + c$.

In my textbook (Foundations math seventh edition) they are elaborating on a particular way of finding a factorised expression of a quadratic expression where $a > 1$.

It goes as follows: (1) $S = 2x^2 + 5x - 3$ ; (2) $2S = 2(2x^2) + 2(5x) - 6$ ; (3) $2S = (2x)^2 + 5 (2x) - 6$ ; after which they take $2x$ to be $z$ so that we can move further in the process with the expression $z^2 + 5z - 6$.

The steps after (3) I understand very well. But I cannot wrap my head around the way they say that $2(2x^2) + 2(5x)$ may be written as $(2x)^2 + 5(2x)$

Can someone explain why this rewrite rule can be applied: i.e. which rules allow such rewriting?

Comment: One can treat it as an application of the associative and commutative properties of multiplication.  We have $2(2x^2) = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot x \cdot x$;  that is equal to $2 \cdot x \cdot 2 \cdot x$.  This can be written as $(2x)^2$.  Similarly $2(5x) = 2 \cdot 5 \cdot x = 5 \cdot 2 \cdot x = 5(2x)$.

Comment: Brian Tung, many thanks writing out $2(2x^2)$ as $2×2×x×x$ made me see it!

Answer (score 2):

Going off my comment: We can treat it as an application of the associative and commutative properties of multiplication.  We have

\begin{align}
2(2x^2) & = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot x \cdot x \\
        & = 2 \cdot x \cdot 2 \cdot x \\
        & = (2x)^2
\end{align}

Similarly, we have

\begin{align}
2(5x) & = 2 \cdot 5 \cdot x \\
      & = 5 \cdot 2 \cdot x \\
      & = 5(2x)
\end{align}